# How to Call a RCP perspective from IntroPage(HTML) of RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have built a RCP application with Intropage in HTML. I also have other perspectives in the application. How do call (or load) a perspective from a button click in the HTML intro page ?

Comment: An RCP written using what? Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can find views like

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getViewRegistry().find(id)
```

or perspectives like

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getPerspectiveRegistry().getPerspectives()
```

Comment: yes but how do I call it from the HTML page.
have written a javascript to call java class from same folder . but it does not work